# The space of all structures with countable universe and a given signature.

Tags: general-topology, logic, model-theory

Let $L=\langle \{R_i\}\cup\{f_j\}\rangle , i \in I, j\in J$ be a signature and consider the space of all L structures with countable universe $\mathbb{N}$. This space is mentioned in [the paper here](https://archive.org/details/arxiv-math0305241/page/n16/mode/2up) on the connection between topological dynamics (specifically extreme amenability of topological groups), structural ramsey theory and Fraisse theory.)

$$X_L = \Pi_i 2^{\mathbb{n}^n_i} \times \Pi_j \mathbb{n}^{\mathbb{n^m_j}}$$

It is mentioned in the paper that if $L$ is relational, then $X_L$ is compact (homeomorphic to $2^{\mathbb{N}}$.

The thing is, in general I am struggling to understand what the topology on this space is. It is just a countable product space of spaces with discrete topology. Is this space significant in any other contexts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you’ve written for $X_L$ isn’t quite right: it should be

$$X_L=\prod_{i\in I}2^{\Bbb N^{n_i}}\times\prod_{j\in J}\Bbb N^{\Bbb N^{m_j}}\;.$$

Saying that $L$ is relational is just saying that $J=\varnothing$, so that $X_L=\prod_{i\in I}2^{\Bbb N^{n_i}}$, which is the product of countably infinitely many discrete two-point spaces and therefore homeomorphic to $2^{\Bbb N}$. This is an extremely important space: it is homeomorphic to the (middle-thirds) [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) and in various guises crops up all over topology, real analysis, and set theory.

If $J\ne\varnothing$ and at least one $m_j>0$, $\prod_{j\in J}\Bbb N^{\Bbb N^{m_j}}$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$, the Cartesian product of countably infinitely many copies of $\Bbb N$ with the discrete topology, which in turn is homeomorphic to the space of irrational numbers with the topology that it inherits from the real line with its usual topology, a space that **also** crops up in a variety of places.

Topologically speaking, then, $X_L$ is homeomorphic to the Cantor set, the irrationals, or the Cartesian product of the two, and that product is actually homeomorphic to the irrationals, since $2^{\Bbb N}\times\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}=(2\times\Bbb N)^{\Bbb N}=\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$, so it has a nice and very well understood topological structure.

**Added:** Andreas Blass reminds me that there are a couple of degenerate cases as well. When $L$ consists of nothing but a finite, non-empty set of constant symbols ($0$-ary function symbols), $X_L$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb N$, a countably infinite discrete space, and when $L$ has no symbols at all, $X_L$ is just the one-point space.

Comment: Thank you very much for your informative reply! I have not formally studied set theory so this is a bit new to me. Would I be correct in thinking that the class of all finite structures is a compact and closed subset of this space? It would seem to me to be homeomorphic to the binary sequences that are eventually zero, or rationals if $J \neq \emptyset$, so it seems like the space $C_0(X)$ of a classical function space $L_\infty(X)$ say. What about classes of structures that are hereditary or have joint embedding property/amalgamation property?

Comment: I ask because I am trying to understand Fraisse classes, and I think they might be an topologically interesting subspace of $X_L$

Comment: An additional point I just thought of: is there an analogous space for structures on uncountable universes? I presume we can construct it, but maybe it isn't a particularly nice space like $X_L$

Comment: Nice answer! Brian, on a personal note, how does feel to be so close to 500k? this is going to be such a milestone for MSE!

Comment: @ILoveMath: Thanks! In all honesty it kind of sneaked up on me while I was away!

Comment: @Meep: You’re very welcome. This is a bit outside my area, but it appears to me that the structures for $L$ with universe some finite subset of $\Bbb N$ would not be a closed subset of $X_L$; I’d have to give it more thought, but I rather think that that they are a **dense** subset. For structures on a universe of uncountable cardinality $\kappa$ just replace $\Bbb N$ by a discrete space of cardinality $\kappa$. The analogues of the Cantor set and the irrationals aren’t quite so ubiquitous, but they’re still pretty nice, well-understood spaces.

Comment: @Meep "Would I be correct in thinking that the class of all finite structures is a compact and closed subset of this space? It would seem to me to be homeomorphic to the binary sequences that are eventually zero" The space of eventually-zero binary sequences is **not** compact or even closed; it's dense and properly $F_\sigma$.

Comment: @Meep "Is there an analogous space for structures on uncountable universes?" Sure - just look at higher powers! Taking for example the signature consisting of a single binary relation, the space of structures in this signature with domain $\kappa$ is just $2^\kappa$ (= the $\kappa$-fold power of the two-element discrete space). Per Tychonoff it remains compact, and this continues to be a very useful fact.

Comment: @bof: You’re absolutely right; I clearly wasn’t thinking. Thanks!

Comment: Some degenerate cases: If you allow constant symbols as $0$-ary function symbols, then there's another possibility for $X_L$, namely an infinite discrete space when $L$ consists of just finitely many (but at least one) constant symbols.  And if $L$ has no symbols at all, then $X_L$ is a single point.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: True, and the author definitely does allow constant symbols as $0$-ary function symbols; I’ll add a brief comment to that effect. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

It's not that alien a space: it's just the Cantor set (viewed as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology), or the set of infinite binary sequences with the topology generated by finite initial segments (the "space of paths through the binary tree"). I think much of the mystery around it comes from our "geometric" expectations, which bias us towards manifolds. Cantor space isn't really geometric (e.g. it's totally disconnected and homeomorphic to its square), but that shouldn't make it particularly mysterious.

Cantor space has some nice properties. It's usually first sighted when learning about cardinality (and in particular how you don't need "long" intervals to have "large" cardinality), but it has many more roles:

- Compact metric spaces are [all](https://mathoverflow.net/a/5388/8133) (up to homeomorphism) continuous images of Cantor space.
- Cantor space is uniquely characterized up to homeomorphism as a compact totally disconnected metrizable space without isolated points. In particular, the topological space of $p$-adic integers is homeomorphic to Cantor space.
- In general, Cantor space is a great source of counterexamples in topology and analysis:

  - Cantor space - or more precisely, [its "fat" images in $\mathbb{R}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) - demonstrates the fundamental difference between *measure* and *category*.
  - The Cantor set can be used to build a simple [indecomposable continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indecomposable_continuum#Bucket_handle_example) (which can lead one to conjecture, and then eventually build, a [*hereditarily* indecomposable continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-arc)).
- Cantor space and its relatives (namely higher products of the two-element discrete space) show up *everywhere* in logic: e.g. the space of types over a structure, or the space of complete theories in the topological proof of compactness for propositional logic, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wish I could accept two answers :(